# Multiple pages in postscript file

Tags: postscript

I have to create a postscript file where are multiple pages with different properties and graphics. That doesn't sound complicated since showpage is used, but the problem is I have to put showpage into a repeat loop. I don't understand how this can even work. It should look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DwmY.jpg). Please help, because I'm not familiar with postscript that much

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the problem (there is insufficient information given, as implied by Stepohen Rauch's comment).

You have no explained why showpage needs to be called in a repeat loop. The showpage operator does not control either the media size or the content of the marks on the page, so it is entirely possible (if cumbersome and unlikely) to do so if there is a genuine need.

The 'enter image description here' link doesn't help any since it simply shows 2 graphics with no explanation of the problem.

Comment: yes, there is not much information. I have got a task where my teacher requires a document with 10 pages and everything has to be created with showpage in a repeat loop. If it wasn't that, it would be easy. :( . still thanks

Comment: Yes, it sounded like a class assignment. There are many ways you could tackle this, including simply redefining showpage to do something in addition to ejecting the page. The simplest solution is probably to create an array of executable arrays. Each executable array contains the definition of the marking operations on the page. Then run a loop, on each iteration of the loop pull the corresponding executable array from the main array, execute it, then execute showpage. Depending what the exact assignment is there may be other solutions.